# how to get auth_user in python web request

Tags: python

I'm new to python . I want to make a basic auth in a web project , is there any way get HTTP authentication variables like the '$_SERVER['php_auth_user']' in php ?
I'm using the FF's torando server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any particular support for Basic auth in Tornado, so you'd have to do it yourself by base64-decoding the `Authorization` header.

Probably something like:

```
import base64

class BasicAuthHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        scheme, _, token= self.request.headers.get('Authorization', '').partition(' ')
        if scheme.lower()=='basic':
            user, _, pwd= base64.decodestring(token).partition(':')
            # if pwd matches user:
                return user
        return None

    def get(self):
        if not self.get_current_user():
            self.set_status(401)
            self.set_header('WWW-Authenticate', 'basic realm="Example site"')
            # produce error/login page for user to see if they press escape to
            # cancel authorisation
            return
```

(not tested as I don't run Tornado.)

Answer (score 0):

The [tornado-http-auth](https://github.com/gvalkov/tornado-http-auth) module provides basic and digest authentication for Tornado. A brief usage example would be:

```
import tornado.ioloop
from tornado_http_auth import BasicAuthMixin
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application

class MainHandler(BasicAuthMixin, RequestHandler):
    def prepare(self):
        self.get_authenticated_user(realm='Protected', auth_func=credentials.get)

    def get(self):
        self.write('Hello %s' % self._current_user)

app = Application([
    (r'/', MainHandler),
])

app.listen(8080)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```